# the first call or first call

Tags: grammar

Which one is correct: 'Chemotherapy should be **the** first call of treatment for cancer' or Chemotherapy should be first call of treatment for cancer'?

Comment: I don't find the cited example idiomatic. I'd use either *Chemotherapy should be the first **choice** for cancer treatment* or *Chemotherapy should be the first **port of call** for cancer treatment*.

Comment: Or "the first *course* of treatment". [*course*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/course) - "3. *countable noun [usually singular]* - A course of action is an action or a series of actions that you can do in a particular situation."

Answer (score 2):

In that context, drop *the* if, and only if, *first* acts as a marker to enumerate a list, as it does in the following examples (emphasis, mine):

- He is **first** kind, no-nonsense, selfless, nice, sweet and helpful. He is **later** mean, evil, dangerous, cold-blooded, ruthless, ag[g]ressive, murderous, power-hungry and bad.
  [- Tom and Jerry wiki, about the main antagonist](http://tomandjerry.wikia.com/wiki/J.W.)
- he is **first** happy for me finding a rewarding field for my career, and **secondly**, he is happy that it was his vision that caused the difference
  [- Statistical Physics, High Energy, Condensed Matter and Mathematical Physics ... by C. H. Oh](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=DzRkDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA515&lpg=PA515&dq=%22he%20is%20first%20happy%22&source=bl&ots=LdSufVMP0V&sig=thdAaui15eOcbc3EIH2AiIuqWV8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLmMrB3Z3YAhWIo5QKHdb9ASUQ6AEIPjAI#v=onepage&q=%22he%20is%20first%20happy%22&f=false)

> **first** *ordinal number*
>   2.2 Firstly; in the first place (used to introduce a main point or reason)
>   ‘first, it is wrong that the victims should have no remedy’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/first)

I don't think your example can be read that way. There, "first" isn't marking an element of a list, but instead acts to qualify *call* (or the noun phrase headed by *call*).

> **first** *ordinal number*
>   1 Coming before all others in time or order; earliest; 1st.
>   ‘It is hoped to have everything in order for the first performance at the end of November.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/first)

This usage is marked by a determiner before the word *first*. So in your example, retain *the*.